# Добавить поле поиска в GridView

Tags: php, yii2

В БД есть три таблицы, свзянанные внешними ключами.

```
-- `country`
   `id`
   `name`

-- `region`
   `id`
   `name`
   `country_id`

-- `city`
   `id`
   `name`
   `region_id`
```

Все связи настроены.

На странице `city/index` вывод данных вот так:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
//...
'columns' => [
        'region.country.name',
        'region.name',
        'name',
     ],
]) ?>
```

Для полей `region.name` и `name` есть поле поиска, но как добавить поле поиска для `region.country.name` ?

Comment: Или мне в модели `city` как то надо объявить геттер?

Comment: И вообще стандартными средствами это можно реализовать или только через дополнительные расширения

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить в вашу serch model свойство с названием поля для поиска
затем когда будут приняты параметры с гета, проверьте пришло ли оно и дополните запрос новым условием  по типу

```
        if (!is_null($this->вашесвтйоство)) {
            $query->andFilterWhere([ChatMessageReceiverModel::tableName() . '.deleted' => $this->deleted]);
        }
```